# jQuery Events on Elements in an UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have some elements inside an UpdatePanel which may or may be displayed, depending on various conditions.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server">
            <img id="clickableImage" src="/path/to/image.png" alt="Clickable Image" />
            <span id="specialMessage">You clicked on the image!</span>
        <asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'm trying to wire it up so that the specialMessage SPAN is shown when the clickableImage IMG is clicked with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickableImage").click(function() {
        $("#specialMessage").show();
    });

    $("#specialMessage").draggable();
});
```

However, since MyPanel is often not visible when the page loads (but it may be visible later based on user interaction), the events aren't hooked up.  Is there a way that I can hook up these events even if MyPanel is not visible on the initial page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

            prm.add_endRequest(function() {
                bindPageEvents(); /// insert bind function here! [I have it as an actual function() to avoid writing it out twice when I use this method]
            });
        </script>
```

Will re-bind your events to elements created in an UpdatePanel.

So, you just put

`function bindPageEvents(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickableImage").click(function() {
        $("#specialMessage").show();
    });`

```
$("#specialMessage").draggable();
```

});
});

in the code at some point outside the update panel.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `$.live()` method to attach the logic for dynamically-added elements.

```
$("#clickableImage").live("click", function() {
    $("#specialMessage").show();
});
```

This will apply to all present instances of `#clickableImage` as well as all future instances too.

Comment: Using live() in .ready() is ok?  And if I wanted the specialMessage SPAN to use ui.draggable?

Comment: Yes it is. If fact its the ideal place to use it :-)

Comment: Not so ideal indeed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024018/using-domcontentready-considered-anti-pattern-by-google