# What is the difference between DOMContentLoaded and DOMContentReady?

Tags: javascript, html, domready

[According to the MDN wiki,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) `DOMContentLoaded` will fire when "page's DOM is ready, [although] the referenced stylesheets, images, and subframes may not be done loading."

What about `DOMContentReady`? Is it just an alias?

Comment: `DOMContentReady`? Is that a real event type? Source please.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/extensions/options.html?view=markup&pathrev=148936

Comment: Is that code your only source? If yes, it might be a typo.

Comment: It is also used all over [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2024018/1048572) - but no link to a spec or such.

Comment: Apart from that, there is a [`readyStateChange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.onreadystatechange)

Comment: @Bergi I think the participants of that thread just mistook it for the actual "DOMContentLoaded" event type.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It's not a typo; the commit that introduced this code [has been peer-reviewed](https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/10824073). If you still don't believe me, just google `DOMContentReady`.

Comment: @seriousdev Peer-review is done by humans, and is therefore subject to mistakes. Google gives 4400 results which all seem to be pointing to user discussions, with no results pointing to actual documentation. I reason that it's a typo or a *lapsus memoriae*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm making the claim that the event type "DOMContentReady" does not exist in current implementations (meaning, that no current implementation fires such an event type), and that appearances of such a name are merely *lapsus memoriae*.

The name "DOMContentLoaded" is not easily remembered, and since the jQuery library uses the method `.ready()` to bind this event type, I guess, some people just mistakenly used the name "DOMContentReady" to refer to the correct name "DOMContentLoaded".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `DOMContentReady` is not a standard event. Just stick with `DOMContentLoaded`.